# Android Timber logging multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Consider the following simple setup. 1 Fragment with 1 ViewModel:

*Fragment*

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.testLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            Log.d("###", "whattt")
        })
    }
}
```

*ViewModel*

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val myVariable = Log.d("###", "Test")

    val testLiveData = MutableLiveData(false)
}
```

**Why do I get a log output from both Fragment and ViewModel up to three times??**

```
D/###: Test
D/###: whattt
D/###: Test
D/###: Test
D/###: whattt
D/###: whattt
```

Comment: It completely depends on how you use `TestFragment` in your code.

Comment: Very good hint! i found out that the fragment in my demo app indeed gets initialized 3 times. But in my "real" app it does not...I will investigate further and update the question if need be. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the comment from @tynn I realized that the problem might come from some actions happening before the fragment actually is involved. Long story short: I have a multi-module project: 1 app module, 1 data module and 1 network module.
Both the network module and the app module were planting a Timber DebugTree...So everything was logged twice *facepalm*

I searched a little bit if there is a good way to keep the modules independent in this regard. The only thing I could found was this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872754/990129

```
object TimberLogImplementation {

    fun initLogging() {
        if(Timber.treeCount() != 0) return
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Timber.plant(DebugTree())
        else Timber.plant(ReleaseTree())
    }

}
```